# Terminal - how to redirect command with the output to the file?

Tags: bash

When I want to append a command output to the log file and also print it on the terminal I use the following command:

```
ls 2>&1 | tee -a log.txt
```

Is it possible to redirect also a command which has been executed ? Then an example content of the `log.txt` will look like this:

```
ls
file1
file2
dir1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a helper function to generalize this.

```
#!/bin/bash

logged() {
  { echo "$1"; "$@"; } 2>&1 | tee -a log.txt
}

# Will run command ls with output logging
logged ls
logged ls -t /home
...
```

The other usual way to 'log' commands executed is `xtrace` (`set -x`) but might be not so suitable for your case. If you want to try it you can at least get rid of the usual '+' prefix by setting `PS4=''`.